# Is it possible to share the complete codebase between angular web app and ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am developing an app with Ionic 4. And I've just recognized, that one can simply run ng serve and use my app in the browser as usual.

Now, if I want to build an angular web app and an Android and IOS with ionic 4, can I do that all in one project?

Comment: The concept you are looking for is monorepo. Look at this [link\](https://medium.com/mitterio/multirepo-to-lerna-js-monorepo-80f6657cb443). It uses lerna.

Comment: The concept of ionic 4 is that you can use Ionic (UI Layer) with all kind of Frameworks (Angular/React/Vue/Stencil/or none at all).. For example, you can use Ionic with Capacitor or Cordova to build an iOS/Android app and could use the same Codebase to build this app as a web app again with cordova or capacitor (the plugins are supporting web as well) - [check out for more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2jRs7Qqai8)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. (Nowadays im developing one of this), same code base for both, APK and webapp.

You can turn your Angular webapp into PWA with two commands, this will enable support on mobiles adding your webapp as if would be a native app.

Check Angular doc for more info: [Angular PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)